# Swap keys in ruby hash

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap

In Ruby, how do I swap keys in a Hash?

Let's say I have the following Hash:

```
{:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3, :four=>4 }
```

That I want to transform into:

```
{:one=>1, :three=>2, :two=>3, :four=>4}
```

which is, swap keys :two and :three but leave their values unchanged.

What is the most effective solution for this?

Comment: Is it important to keep the order? If not, just swap the values instead.

Comment: Would you explain the reason behind the request?

Comment: It is important to keep the order. In real life situation I get a collection (array of hashes) as a result of running a mssql stored procedure, which is then represented as html table by a helper. I need to change the order of several columns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would be:

```
h = {:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3, :four => 4}
h[:two], h[:three] = h[:three], h[:two]
```

If this is something you need to do regularly, you can define a method on Hash that allows for a prettier syntax:

```
class Hash
  def swap!(a, b)
    self[a], self[b] = self[b], self[a] if key?(a) && key?(b)
    self
  end

  def swap(a, b)
    self.dup.swap!(a, b)
  end
end
```

Note, however, that both of these solutions will preserve the order of key-value pairs in the hash. If you want to actually swap the keys as well as their values, you can do this:

```
class Hash
  def swap(a, b)
    self.inject(Hash.new) do |h, (k,v)|
      if k == a
        h[b] = self[a]
      elsif k == b
        h[a] = self[b]
      else
        h[k] = v
      end
      h
    end
  end
end
{:one => 1, :two => 2, :three => 3, :four => 4}.swap(:two, :three)
# results in {:one=>1, :three=>2, :two=>3, :four=>4}
```

Though I'm not sure why you'd want to do that.

Comment: +1 for the first two lines.  (I think you could have skipped the rest.) Aside: you may consider using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), rather than `inject` in situations where, with `inject`, you need to return the object (here a hash) to the iterator at the end of the block. That's not necessary with `each_with_object`.

Comment: Learn something new every day :)
I wasn't even aware of `each_with_object`, though I occasionally comb through `Enumerable` methods to remind myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for complete answer @migimunz, extending Hash class with swap! and swap methods did the trick in my situation.

Comment: One way to think of this is to use `each_with_object` whenever `inject`'s argument would be `{}` or `[]`.

Comment: Wastrox, if you are using Ruby 2.0, you might want to consider using [`Module#refine`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-refine), rather than changing the class `Hash` globally. More on `refine` [here](http://dev.af83.com/2012/11/05/ruby-2-0-module-refine.html).

Comment: Nice snippet for adding the Hash method. I wonder where you usually put such extension file in a rails project?

Answer (score 1):

Perl makes this really easy, but Ruby doesn't have hash slicing, so we have to do it in a bit more round-about manner:

```
hash = {:one=>1, :two=>2, :three=>3, :four=>4 }
new_key_order = [:one, :three, :two, :four]

new_hash = Hash[new_key_order.zip(hash.values)]
# => {:one=>1, :three=>2, :two=>3, :four=>4}
```

This works because Ruby remembers the insertion order of hashes so `values` returns them in the original order always. If you wanted to do this without relying on insertion order, it's a minor change:

```
old_key_order = [:one, :two,   :three, :four]
new_key_order = [:one, :three, :two,   :four]

new_hash = Hash[new_key_order.zip(hash.values_at(*old_key_order))]
# => {:one=>1, :three=>2, :two=>3, :four=>4}
```

Notice that I aligned the columns of keys to make what changed really stand out. That's something we do in our team to help make it obvious when something is changing in code that looks very similar.

*It's possible to use parallel assignment, but that adds up to messy code really quick when you're dealing with a lot of columns, or fields.* It's easier to define the input order and output orders, like above, so you have a very visual reference to the mappings, then pass them to `zip` and let it do the hard work, then coerce it back into a hash.

As an aside, here's how I'd do it in Perl. This is using the debugger:

```
perl -de 1

  DB<1> %hash = ('one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4)

  DB<2> x \%hash
0  HASH(0x7fceb94afce8)
   'four' => 4
   'one' => 1
   'three' => 3
   'two' => 2
  DB<3> @hash{'one', 'three', 'two', 'four'} = @hash{'one', 'two', 'three', 'four'}

  DB<4> x \%hash
0  HASH(0x7fceb94afce8)
   'four' => 4
   'one' => 1
   'three' => 2
   'two' => 3
```

Basically, Perl has the ability to retrieve, or assign, with the equivalent of Ruby's `values_at` by coercing a hash to an array and defining the order of the keys. It's a wonderfully powerful tool in Perl when you want to restructure a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

There is no notion of order in a hash.

Comment: That used to be true, however, since Ruby 1.9, Ruby maintains insertion order. It's not a sorted-hash though.

Comment: @theTinMan I wasn't talking about Ruby but about hash semantics. True that the implementation may have a notion of order, however that is not something you should build on.

Comment: Actually, we're guaranteed that Ruby's hash insertion order will be maintained. This was discussed quite a bit when it was first implemented. Other languages might do something differently, but we're talking about Ruby here.

Comment: I agree that it is quite risky to take advantage of order of keys in hash (especially if it is being kept in a db). Unfortunately, the question was about another thing.